# PHP Error on Structure manage entries page

Tags: php, error, structure

I'm experiencing the following PHP error on a site running [Structure](http://buildwithstructure.com) (3.3.6), and am having some trouble debugging it.

The text of the error is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 106
>
> Filename: views/index.php
>
> Line Number: 45

It is being output inline in my entry tree like so:

[image: Screenshot of error]

The code on line 45 of structure's `views/index.php` is:

```
$add_url  = BASE.AMP.'C=content_publish'.AMP.'M=entry_form'.AMP.'channel_id='.$page['channel_id']
.AMP.'parent_id='.$eid.AMP.'template_id='.$site_pages['templates'][$eid];
```

*(Line break added for readability)*

I can't see anything unique/wrong with the entry that is triggering this notice, and Structure is otherwise working fine. The only real reason I want to clean it up is that it's visible to the client in the CP (not my server and I can't edit PHP error prefs unfortunately).

Has anyone seen this before/know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the [Debug Mode for Page Data](http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/debug_mode_for_page_data/) yet? Sometimes that helps clear up errors. Make a backup before running it just in case.

Comment: Thanks, have run it through debug mode but unfortunately the notice remains

Comment: Feel free to post these types of questions to the official [Structure Support](https://structure.tenderapp.com) site so we can help you quickly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is probably `$site_pages['templates'][$eid]`. A couple of obvious things to check would be:

- What's in the templates array? Find out with `var_dump($site_pages['templates']);`
- Check where `$eid` is set.

It's a bit of a leap of faith, but since the error looks like it relates to a template that isn't there, is there any chance you've assigned that page to a template which has since been deleted?

Comment: So this was so close to being correct it's uncanny. `var_dump($site_pages['templates'])` outputs a pretty massive multidimensional array, but following your hunch about templates I tried editing the Structure template field for the entry, and then changing it back again to the value I wanted and, boom! Fixed. From the look of things Structure was referencing the wrong `template_id` somehow, even though `template_name` was correct and the entry was rendering fine on the front end. Weird. Anyway, thanks Dom!

Comment: No worries, glad to hear that sorted it.

Answer (score -3):

If you really just want to suppress the error message, add an "@" before the PHP code wich is responsible for your error.

I think  $site_pages['templates'] just does not have an index with number 106, so in this case you could change line 45 into:

```
$add_url  = BASE.AMP.'C=content_publish'.AMP.'M=entry_form'.AMP.'channel_id='.$page['channel_id'].AMP.'parent_id='.$eid.AMP.'template_id='.@$site_pages['templates'][$eid];
```

Please consider another option as this is not the best solution ;)